# How to read RadioButton state

Tags: android, radio-button, android-alertdialog

I have an xml file called options.xml
I use it to create my AlertDialog. I also added a Done button for the AlertDialog.
When the done button is pressed, the onClick method bellow is called. However, no matter which RadioButton I have checked before clicking Done, I always get the first RadioButton as checked and the others as unchecked.
I assume that what I am doing bellow just read the xml values and not the actual run time values? Then how do I read the real run-time values?

```
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) ;
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.options, null);
            RadioButton a1 = (RadioButton)layout.findViewById(R.id.radio0);
            RadioButton a2= (RadioButton)layout.findViewById(R.id.radio1);
            RadioButton a3 = (RadioButton)layout.findViewById(R.id.radio2);
            RadioButton a4 = (RadioButton)layout.findViewById(R.id.radio3);
            boolean b1 = a1.isChecked();
            boolean b2 = a2.isChecked();
            boolean b3 = a3.isChecked();
            boolean b4 = a4.isChecked();

    }
```

EDIT: The solution I used "Thanks, I didn't check the second option but I found that AlertDialog has findViewById and it was just a matter of calling that after creating the dialog. (Not needed to be done inside onCreate or any other special function). You just need to remember to call findViewById after you called show() for the dialog, otherwise it worn't work"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, you're reading the xml values of them because you're trying to findViewById on a layout inflated directly from xml.

You can either use mContext.findViewById(..) if mContext is an Activity. Failing that, define your RadioButtons somewhere in the onCreateDialog(..) rather than inside onClick(..), and then use these to determine isChecked().

This is a similar example where I had to get the value of an EditText from inside the onClick(..) method. If you need the `final` modifier, Eclipse should tell you. This is all in the onCreateDialog(..) method.

```
case FIRST_TRANSLATE:
        View view = mHost.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.first_translate, null);
        //Define your radiobuttons here
        final EditText mLanguage = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        b.setView(view)
        .setTitle(R.string.dialog_first_translate_title)
        .setPositiveButton(sOkay, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                //Retrieve their values here
                mHost.getSharedPreferences(States.INTERNAL_PREFS, 0).edit().putString("deflang", mLanguage.getText().toString()).commit();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

        }).create();
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't check the second option but I found that AlertDialog has findViewById and it was just a matter of calling that after creating the dialog. (Not needed to be done inside onCreate or any other special function).
You just need to remember to call findViewById after you called show() for the dialog, otherwise it worn't work.